# direct sum of rows of $A$ and $\ker A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw such a statement: $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix with full rank and $m<n$, then $\mathbb{R}^n=\ker A \oplus \text{span }{A^T}$. I don't know how to prove it, in particular, I don't know how to construct such a decomposition. I can only prove the intersection of two space are $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is that the intersection is $\{0\}$ (which you already have) and that their dimensions add to $n$; you get this last part from the rank-nullity theorem.